# PostgreSQL - Merging three columns into one adds slash notation to end of IP addresses

Tags: database, postgresql, merge, ip, ip-address

**The problem (greatly simplified for the purposes of explaining my question):**

In Postgres I am trying to combine three columns from a table into one column in a View but at the end of ipaddresses slash notation is being added when I do not want it (**NOTE:** the slash notation IS NOT at the end of the ip addresses in my table to begin with).

**What I am doing:**

In my table I have a column called 'ipaddress' which is type 'inet'.

In my table I have a column called 'firstname' which is type 'text'.

In my table I have a column called 'age' which is type 'integer'.

**Using the following sql statement in a View I am trying to combine these three columns into one:**

```
SELECT (thetablename.ipaddress || thetablename.firstname || thetablename.age) 
AS personal_details
FROM thetablename
```

This all works perfectly and merges the three columns into one, **however for the ipaddresses it adds slash notation to the end of it as shown below:**

**The output I am getting:**

```
-------------------------
    personal_details
-------------------------
192.168.0.199/32 Dave 65    <-- as you can see it is adding /32 but i do not want it to
192.168.0.100/32 Paul 56
192.168.0.121/32 Lucy 28
```

I cannot seem to prevent it from adding the '/32' slash notation to the end of the ip addresses.

**I have tried explicitly specifying the type but this has no effect:**

```
SELECT (thetablename.ipaddress::inet || thetablename.firstname::text || thetablename.age::integer) 
AS personal_details
FROM thetablename
```

There must be something obvious I am overlooking but cannot work out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **host** function instead of the default cast formatter.

So use:

```
SELECT (host(thetablename.ipaddress::inet) || thetablename.firstname::text || thetablename.age::integer) 
AS personal_details
FROM thetablename
```

The `/32` you have is the network mask added by default with the default formatter.

You have several functions available with `inet` type: [check this list of functions and results](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly, thanks for the link as well. At the moment I don't have any spacing between the data from the three combined columns so its just `192.168.0.199Dave65`. What is considered the best way to do that (eg .. `' ' ||` or .. `'<br/>' ||`) thanks a lot.

Comment: use **concat_ws**, search for it in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-FUNCTIONS-TABLE, this will handle nicely NULL values and separators, as 'foo'||NULL is NULL...